# opening 2 links on click without getting one blocked as a "pop up"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, href

I want to open 2 URLs on click.
This can be done through jquery, javascript whatever I don't care.
I prefer lightweight and speed but at this point anything is fine with me.

I tried including onclick in the a href and also open.window in jquery.

Both gave me a: "popup blocked"

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct - but it *is* a popup. You can't avoid that.

Comment: really there's no magic way of doing this? maybe redirecting to a second page that then redirects to a new tab and open a new page in it's own tab?

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai how do I find this walk around, I am okay with visiting those sites I guess, as long as it gives me this code.

Comment: are the links you're opening in the same domain? If not, the browser is properly alerting you....

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai thanks, what I meant was how do I find that code on that website?

Comment: :) You need to view the source and track it :(

Comment: _“really there's no magic way of doing this?”_ – if there was, that would render popup blockers rather useless, because then every Evil Advertiser (that is not as pure of heart and filled with only good intentions as you of course are …) would use it too. Pretty effin’ obvious, once you actually think about it, no?

Comment: If you need this within a closed, administrated network, then get the popup blockers configured accordingly. If you need it in the “open internet”, for every user – then your only option is to either alert them beforehand that they should please configure their popup blocker accordingly, by adding an exception for your domain f.e. (if they are actually allowed to – they might be inside an administrated network themselves) – or find another way of displaying your information that doesn’t need multiple windows/tabs opened simultaneously.

Comment: is there any difference if I want to open 2 pages from the same domain on click ?

Comment: Alas, it is now done :) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
```

> JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
  window.open('http://yoururl2.com');
});
```

> Otherwise do it in simple way

```
    <a href="http://yoururl1.com" onclick="window.open('http://yoururl2.com'); return true;">multiopen</a>
```

Comment: this still gave me a popup alert :(

Answer (score 0):

Setup a link with `target="_blank"` to ensure the popup opens as `_blank` is okay with all browsers.

Then after it is opened, substitute current address with javascript's `window.location`;

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" class="bob">2 links</a>
<script>
$('a.bob').on('click', function(e){
    window.location.href="http://yahoo.com"
});
</script>
```